# Observers in every episode?

Tags: fringe

I have recently started watching Fringe and as a newbie to watching Fringe I have been advised that I need to spot all of the observers, and that they're present in every episode every aired.

Is this true? Are there actually observers present in every episode? I feel like I'm going out of my mind trying to spot individual frames that have observers in them...

Comment: This question already has an answer on [Sci-Fi Stack Exchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22909/does-an-observer-appear-in-every-episode-of-fringe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an Observer in *every* episode. [FringePedia provides an Observer Appearance guide](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Observer_Appearance) with photos of each appearance and time stamps of where the Observer can be observed from the episode.

You can also search for the [episode reviews](http://www.sfx.co.uk/search/fringe+episode+review) on the SFX website, every review has a section called 'Observing the Observer' that tells you where to spot them.

**EDITORIAL NOTE:** This great answer was given by [philpursglove](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/186/philpursglove) on [SciFi&Fantasy.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22915/23386) and copied.